# How to set value in createMaterialBottomTabNavigator from AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage

I am using createMaterialBottomTabNavigator , but before export that i want to assign value for its navigationOptions

```
barStyle: { backgroundColor:someVariable}
```

here problem is , i want to get value of `someVariable` from AsyncStorage.
And it returns promise , because of that createMaterialBottomTabNavigator is getting exported first , after that I get value of `someVariable` . I can't write 
export default in `async` function otherwise createMaterialBottomTabNavigator will returned as promise again .Please give suggestions.
I am using redux , but there also i have to update store from AsyncStorage before exporting createMaterialBottomTabNavigator.

Sample code

```
// tabnavigator.js
// I Imported this file in app.js , there i use this in 
createSwitchNavigator
// so this will execute on app starts only

var theme = {};
AsyncStorage.getItem('theam').then((res) => {
    theme = res
});

// I want theme from storage because i am going to apply theme on app 
// start
// Here I can get theme from ReduxStore but i returns the initial one 

const DashTabsNav = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
    ProfileStack: {
        screen: ProfileStack,//this is stack created with 
createStacknavigator , 
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="user" size={25} 
color={tintColor} />),
        },
    },
    Messages: {
        screen: MessageScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarColor: 'red',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="comments" size= 
   {25} color={tintColor} />)
        },

    },
},
    {
        activeColor: 'white',
        inactiveColor: 'white',
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: theme.themeColor },
    },
);
export default DashTabsNav;
```

Comment: Show me a simple code to reproduce the problem. It will help my answer.

Comment: I have manage this thing by putting Stack nav into one component and calling AsyncStorege there

Answer (score 0):

Read https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#overriding-shared-navigationoptions

within your `ProfileScreen` and `MessageScreen` override the header color by doing

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {
    return {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: theme.themeColor,
      },
    };
  };
```